# How to Edit HTML table cell in inline using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, inline-editing

I would like to edit table cell by click on it. I tried but its not updating properly.

When I am trying to update first cell in the first row last column its getting updated. But if i try to update in the middle entire column value getting changed.But for me only one cell value should get changed.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8acoz3fv/)

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editable').click(function(e) {
    var i = 0;
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    e.stopPropagation(); //<-------stop the bubbling of the event here
    var value = $('#' + id).html();

    console.log(id + i);

    updateVal('#' + id, value);

  });

  function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    console.log("Current Element is" + currentEle);
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" maxlength="4" type="text" width="2" value="0" />');
    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        //$(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());


      }

    });

    $(document).click(function() { // you can use $('html')
      $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <tbody id="itemtab" style="width:100%;height:200px !important;font-size:12px">
    <table border="1">
      <th>field1</th>
      <th>field2</th>
      <th>field3</th>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td id="my1" class="editable">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td id="my2" class="editable">20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td id="my3" class="editable">30</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </tbody>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to work just fine if you change the nested event handler from handling a `click` on  `document` to handling a `focusout` on `.thVal`.  e.g. Instead of:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
});
```

Do

```
$(".thVal").focusout(function () {
    $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
});
```

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8acoz3fv/3/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$(document).click` handler is not always reached because sometimes event bubbling is prevented with `e.stopPropagation();` from `$('.editable').click` event.

Optimized and fixed code:

```
$('.editable').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var value = $(this).html();
    updateVal(this, value);
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" maxlength="4" type="text" width="2" value="' + value + '" />');
    $(".thVal", currentEle).focus().keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $(".thVal").replaceWith(function() {
            return this.value;
        });
    });
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8acoz3fv/4/